# Change Position of Newsletter Sidebox in Magento

Tags: magento

Thank you for any help in advance.

I am trying to change the order in which sideboxes appear in magento. Such as the: My Cart, Newsletter, Poll, Recently Viewed Products.

Currently I am trying to make the Newsletter box display last.

In app/design/frontend/default/MY_TEMPLATE/layout/newsletter.xml

I have the following code:

```
    <default>

    <!-- Mage_Newsletter -->
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="newsletter" after="-" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml" />
    </reference>

</default>
```

Yet even with after="-" as shown in the code, the newsletter is still showing up 1st.

I have flushed all caches, and have re-indexed every time I make a change to no avail.

EDIT:

Changing

```
<reference name="left">
```

TO

```
<reference name="right">
```

Moves it to the bottom of the list. However, the column is actually on the left. Any ideas why this works?

Comment: which box is display last other than news letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all in the order of **left**'s `sortedChildren` entries. Try getting rid of the custom *newsletter.xml*, creating a *local.xml* file in your custom theme, and adding the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <action method="unsetChild" block="left">
            <block>left.newsletter</block>
        </action>
        <action method="insert" block="left">
            <block>left.newsletter</block>
            <sib />
            <after>1</after>
        </action>
    </default>
</layout>
```

What this does is remove the block reference from the list of sorted children blocks and then adds it again at the end. Ref. [`Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::insert()` [link]](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php#L625).

I've employed an unused but valid `block` attribute for the `<action />` tag rather than wrap it in `<reference />`. I believe the effect is the same.

Comment: I deleted app/design/frontend/default/MY_TEMPLATE/layout/newsletter.xml and added app/design/frontend/default/MY_TEMPLATE/layout/local.xml as you said, but the newsletter remains at the top.

Answer (score -1):

Check the block names(in layout xml files) which is displaying in your left/right sidebar.
You can find something like this

```
 <reference name="right">
            <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" after="cart_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
 </reference>
```

The above code will display cart sidebar then compare sidebar. Consider this is your last block in your sidebar. If you want to newsletter after this block you have to specify

```
<reference name="right">
        <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="newsletter" after="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml" />
    </reference>
```

You have to specify block names in after/before element tag. Find your left/right sidebars last block name and use that name in your newsletter block.

Comment: Copying the layout XML files is discouraged - better use the local.xml

Comment: I didnt say you to copy layout xml file. You can place this code in your local.xml file. Read the solution first. I told to find name in xml files.